# Есть ли способ в Java читать файлы не из диска, а из оперативной памяти, при этом используя имя файла на диске?

Tags: java

У меня есть библиотека, которая проделывает большую работу и в целом меня устраивает. В этой библиотеке есть один большой недостаток: ее `API`. Выглядит оно примерно так:

```
read("path_from_disk").doSpecialActionForFile()
```

Проблема в том, что сам файл ко мне приходит в бинарном виде в `RAM` и я не могу положить его на диск по соображениям безопасности.

Есть ли способ создать виртуальную ФС в оперативной памяти и читать с нее или решить данную проблему какими-то другими манипуляциями?

Comment: *"я не могу положить его на диск по соображениям безопасности"* звучит не очень убедительно... особенно при том, что вы все равно собираетесь добавлять его в фс. И вообще, все это слишком похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: @user7860670 ФС бывают разные, я могу держать файл только в оперативной памяти. Дискового пространства у меня нет в принципе, тк работа в `kubernetes` без подмантированного диска. По поводу XY, я объяснил суть проблемы и если есть другие варики, то я готов попробовать.

Comment: Чем не подходит [emptyDir volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) c `emptyDir.medium ="Memory"`? В этом случае используется `tmpfs`, и файловая система полностью хранится в RAM

Comment: @RomanKonoval вот это интересная идея, надо попробовать